# How to detect % of black region in an image and exclude image accordingly?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, bounding-box

(SOLVED BUT WITH A NEW PROBLEM PLEASE SEE "UPDATE" BELOW) I loaded some images for skin detection (Please see codes below) and the non-skin regions of these newly saved images are blacked out. I'm looking into zooming/contouring as next steps of preprocessing, but there are a number of images with over 80 or 90% of the photo turned black, since they aren't human photos to begin with. (Should I/Is there a way to remove these images first? I've looked into many sources and still haven't figured out yet. I appreciate any help!

```
min_YCrCb = np.array([0,133,77],np.uint8)
max_YCrCb = np.array([235,173,127],np.uint8)

    files = glob.glob ('%s/*.jpg' %(folder)) 

    # read each image
    for f in files:
        image = cv2.imread(f)
        #detect human skin
        imageYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
        skinRegionYCrCb = cv2.inRange(imageYCrCb,min_YCrCb,max_YCrCb)
        skinYCrCb = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = skinRegionYCrCb)

        #write new images to "newimages" folder
        cv2.imwrite('../data/newimages/ycrcb%04i.png' %i, np.hstack([skinYCrCb]))
```

[Would like to remove images like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBgn9.png)

[Suggestion of ways to remove background on images like this? (zooming/contouring etc?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqtET.png)

UPDATE
I've removed pictures with >80% of black pixels and would like to do bounding box cropping to remove extra black region in the image (see attached images). It works for one picture, but not when I put in a for loop ?

```
files = glob.glob('..data/*.jpg')

i=0
for f in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    #find contours

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #draw these contours
    for cnt in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        img = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0,0,0),1)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(box)

        crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        cv2.imwrite('../data/images%04i.jpg' %i, crop)
        i+=1
```

[Original image with bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91XCJ.jpg)

[Wanted result. but only worked for 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpENT.png)

Comment: Your code is incomplete and you did not include the input images.

Comment: How do you achieve skin detection?

Comment: Apologies! I've updated the codes and attached some images..

Comment: What does it mean to remove the background from the image? What should be the result? Replace black with transparent or something else?

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing bounding box cropping to remove black bkgrd. works for 1 image but in a for loop.. (please see edited post)

Comment: I think no need to use cv2.findContours()

Comment: Thanks! Yes that works too! I changed cv2.findContours to threshold but I still can't make it work for all images in that folder (is there anything wrong with the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate black area percent as:

```
100.*(1.-cv2.mean(skinRegionYCrCb)[0]/255.)
```

Croping image:

```
thresh=cv2.threshold(image, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1] # threshold level is ~10
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```